# How to deal with user data in SQLite database on application update?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my app user can create various lists. These lists are stored in SQLite tables. Also there are other tables in the database that I may want to change in future app updates. I'm not sure what should I do to prevent user data loss in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is function

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(oldVersion < newVersion) {
        switch(oldVersion) {
        case 29:
            migrateFrom24(sqLiteDatabase);
            break;
   }
}
```

in this function you can migrate existing db to new version without data loss

you may add new tables or updte existing tables

here is a sample code:

```
   private static void migrateFrom24(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Table1 RENAME TO Table2");
    db.execSQL("create table Table3 (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,created INTEGER ,account_id TEXT DEFAULT \'\',warehouse_id TEXT DEFAULT \'\',skunit_id TEXT DEFAULT \'\',transaction_id TEXT DEFAULT \'\',sku_quantity TEXT DEFAULT \'\',skunits_price TEXT DEFAULT \'\',sku_uploaded TEXT DEFAULT \'0\')");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE Table4");
    db.execSQL(" ALTER TABLE Table5 ADD COLUMN column1 INTEGER ");
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

When application updates, you need to increase your SQLite database version. Once you will increase your version `onUpgrade(~)` will invoke.

You can drop table and call `onCreate(~)` again in  `onUpgrade(~)` if you have made any changes in the database schema.

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG, "SQLLiteHelper - onUpgrade");
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version "+ oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

        /* Drop older table if existed */
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TABLE_NAME");
   }
```

Your requirements are to maintain the data of the particular table, so need to migrate data to a temporary table and once you will create table with the new structure you can save all data back from the temporary table and you have to delete temporary table after taking your data back.

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG, "SQLLiteHelper - onUpgrade");
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version "+ oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

        /* Moving Data From Old Database to New Database */
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE_NAME AS SELECT * FROM " + "TABLE_NAME");

        /* Deleting Old Table */
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TABLE_NAME");

        /* Creating Same Table with new/updated schema structure*/
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + "TABLE_NAME" + "(-----TABLE COLUMN DETAILS-----)");

        /* Copy back data from temporary tables */
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + "TABLE_NAME" + " SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE_NAME");

        /* Delete temporary table*/
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  TEMP_TABLE_NAME");

        }
```

Hope this will help for your requirements.
Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

App update will not corrupt your DB.

Also, simple SQL migrations will not corrupt it too.

And, may be take a look on ORM's like [ActiveAndroid](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid) for future.

Comment: What if with an update I change database structure and data in it?

Comment: For _your_ tables (not the ones with user-data in), and you don't need to preserve the contents, then drop and recreate with the new structure. For the ones with user-data in (or if you need to preserve data in yours) you need to _migrate_ the data. In simple cases, you _may_ be able to ALTER TABLE but in general, you'd rename the existing table, create the new one, then transfer/massage the data from one to the other. You probably want to add some kind of "DatabaseSchema" setting that records whether the current data is v1, v2, ... etc so you know which changes to apply.